# I want to make a corner div with a border radius

Tags: html, css

I am looking to make something like this

[image]

There can't be a div inside the red area because I am doing collision testing. I need a div(s) to allow me to make a "wall" so that my character can't move inside the div but he can move within the red area. I am making a game of Pac-Man btw.

My current CSS is...

```
div.wall{
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 1000px;
}
div#bottomLeftCornerVertical{
    position: fixed;
    left: 175px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 75px;
    top: 473px;
}
div#bottomLeftCornerHorizontal{

}
```

Where the div.wall is going to be for all my walls, the next one is for the vertical part and the next one(empty one) is for the horizontal piece of this corner.

Comment: give us more about your html strcuture and no need to put a lot of unecessary tags

Comment: just make the whole thing in the canvas. Otherwise its probably a css pseudo element soln.

Comment: how can you do collision testing within a canvas? good suggestion though. ;)

Comment: You can place a div with rounded corner of the opposite color in that corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution #1**: You can use this code to make a canvas inside the `div` and make the game inside the canvas

```css
#myDiv {
  height:275px;
  width:500px;
  background:black;
  border-radius:10px;
}
#myCanvas {
  display:block;
  background:red;
  width:400px;
  height:175px;
  border-radius:0 10px 0 10px;
  transform:translate(100px,0px);
  /*Or however much you need to move it*/
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"><canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas></div>
```

**Solution #2**: If you are going to use other means to make the game you can make a table like this.

```css
#content{
  background:red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:0 10px 0 10px;
}
#side{
  background:black;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border-radius:10px 0 0 0;
}
#bottom{
  background:black;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
}
table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
  background:black;
  border-radius:10px;
 }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td id="side"></td>
<td id="content"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="bottom" colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may rely on pseudo elements and some border to create this:

```css
.wall-top {
  margin-top:20px;
  width:50px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid;
  border-bottom:none;
  border-radius:20px 20px 0 0;
  position:relative;
}
.wall-top:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  height:40px;
  left:-1px;
  top:100%;
  border-left:1px solid;
}
.wall-bottom {
  margin-top:40px;
  width:200px;
  height:30px;
  border:1px solid;
  border-top:0;
  border-radius:0 0 20px 20px;
  position:relative;
}
.wall-bottom:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:-20px;
  height:20px;
  width:50px;
  right:-1px;
  border-top:1px solid;
  border-right:1px solid;
  border-radius:0 20px 0 0;
}
.wall-bottom:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:-40px;
  height:20px;
  width:100px;
  left:50px;
  border-bottom:1px solid;
  border-left:1px solid;
  border-radius:0 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wall-top">
</div>
<div class="wall-bottom">
</div>
```